# Remove response header in grails

Tags: grails, servlets

How can I remove a Header from response in grails. I have a filter which filters requests and in case response contains a specific header I want to remove it is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: The problem is that you can't manipulate the headers after the response has been "committed", so you'll have to find some way to stop the header from being added in the first place.

Comment: I want to do that in a filter after data manipulation in model. so response is not committed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the only way to do this is to have your servlet filter wrap the response with an implementation of [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) that filters out the header you want to remove. So you're not physically removing the header, but when the response is generated only the headers that your response wrapper returns will be included in the HTTP response.

I've not tried this, so if it does work, please let me know!